# Skrill C# implementation shows only Sofortbanking option

Tags: c#

My skrill payment site shows only one option as a payment option.:
[image]

I called them and they said all options are enabled on my merchant account it is the problem on my side, but I don't pass any value which would restrict payment options.

I am building the url like this to receive SID, which later i redirect the user to:

```
public string CreateSkrillUrl(SkrillModel data)
        {
            var url = "https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Timeout = 25000;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write("pay_to_email=" + data.PayToEmail);
                writer.Write("&transaction_id =" + data.TransactionId);
                writer.Write("&language=" + data.Language);
                writer.Write("&amount=" + data.Amount);
                writer.Write("&currency=" + data.Currency);
                writer.Write("&status_url=" + data.StatusUrl);
                writer.Write("&return_url=" + data.ReturnUrl);
                //writer.Write("&payment_type=" + data.PaymentType);
                writer.Write("&prepare_only=1");
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                url += "?sid=" + sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return url;
        }
```

This is the example of built URL:

> https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl?sid=3d5cb6da4b7c06e1c2d4affd91dc2d34

which redirects actually to:

> https://www.skrill.com/pay?sid=507e0d9d0591b8d550c57dd1b0060ed2

Comment: Ok, and what is the question? Use a sentence with a question mark in the end as an indicator.

Comment: @ThomasW. The OP obviously wants to show the other payment methods as well.

Comment: For me it shows IDEAL as well, so it shows 2 options...

Comment: Question is, what am I doing wrong if ? I pasted all stuff how am I doing, and it only shows Sofortbanking as payment option.. Where is creditcard option and other payment wallets?

Comment: The selected country affects the list of payment methods. But that doesn't explain the absence on credit card payments.

Comment: If you use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) do you see something unusal in the requestbody?

Comment: you mean when i send request while building the link?

Answer (score 0):

SofortBanking shows when your amount is less than 0.50. It is not an error... These support people from Skrill didn't have an idea about that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass one more parameter:

writer.Write("&payment_methods=" + "WLT,VSA,MSC");